# Коронавирусом заразилась жительница Москвы, 1958 года рождения. Обязательна ли запятая?

Tags: определения

1. Коронавирусом заразилась жительница Москвы 1958 года рождения.

или

2. Коронавирусом заразилась жительница Москвы, 1958 года рождения.

Как правильно: с запятой или без?

В справочнике Д. Э. Розенталя сказано, что обычно обособляются несогласованные определения, дополняющие или уточняющие представление о лице либо предмете, который сам по себе (без определения) достаточно конкретен, уже известен. В этой роли выступают имена собственные (они выделяют лицо-предмет из ряда подобных), названия лиц по степени родства.

Например: задержан молодой человек 1998 года рождения по подозрению в совершении кражи.

В 1-м предложении, если бы было не "жительница Москвы, а москвичка", то запятая, согласно этому правилу, не нужна была бы.

Но в предложении *Коронавирусом заразилась жительница Москвы 1958 года рождения.* несогласованное определение *1958 года рождения* находится в дистантном положении по отношению к определяемому слову *жительница*, и, следовательно нужно это определение обособить.

Или определяемы словом является *жительница Москвы* и тогда обособлять не нужно?

Answer (score 2):

По-моему, оба варианта верны, по крайней мере, ни один не будет ошибкой.

Однако мне кажется, что в данном случае запятую лучше не ставить, потому что данное лицо (жительница Москвы) без определения недостаточно конкретно. Если бы была названа фамилия, это было бы конкретное лицо, а без фамилии лицо конкретизируется именно указанием года рождения, значит, это важные сведения, не добавочные.